# Why does my monitor flicker until I change resolution?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have one [Sapphire Radeon HD 6950 2 GB DDR5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005X64QAG) Graphics card in my computer.

Everything used to work great. One day my friend and I flipped the switch on it to enable overclocking and I overclocked for a little while. Everything was great. I only overclocked a little bit, nothing too crazy. The default is 800 Mhz, I think I bumped it to 850 Mhz tops.

A couple weeks later I purchased a 1080p monitor to go along side my 1650x1050. Everything was still going great.

A couple weeks after the monitor purchase, I notice that both of my monitors are flickering like crazy. Whenever I move the mouse, or scroll on a browser window for example. Horizontal lines are flickering all over the place. Almost looks like some of the image is displaced in a different location, but happens very fast.

I've realized that if I go into my resolution settings and change the resolution on the 1080p monitor from 1920 x 1080 down to 1650 x 1050 and then SET IT BACK UP to 1920 x 180, everything works great until I reboot the computer. I forget there is even a problem until that point.

I have now disabled the overclocking, and the flickering still occurs on startup.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? And why it is being "fixed" when I reset the resolution manually?

**Update**
I just updated my motherboard BIOS, still flickers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal lines flash randomly over laptop display](http://superuser.com/questions/773911/horizontal-lines-flash-randomly-over-laptop-display)

Answer (score 1):

### Change your Power Plan settings

The power plan is limiting the resources for the graphics card to function properly. Change all the settings to the Maximum Performance.

**How I fixed the problem:**

- Install the latest drivers from the official AMD website (Catalyst 14.0+).
- Change you Power Plan to High Performance (in battery and plugged-in).
- Go to Control Panel>Power Options>Change advanced power settings> ATI Graphics Power Settings> ATI Powerplay settings> On battery, Plugged in: **Maximum Performance**.
- Go to Control Panel>Power Options>Change advanced power settings> PCI Express> Link State Power Management> On battery, Plugged in: **Off**.
- Disable Aero (Choose the *Windows 7 Basic* theme)
- Restart your PC.

**Important:** This will also fix a constant change in the brightness level when you switch between dark and bright apps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have that same computer I had in 2012 to verify your answer. I hope it helps someone else though!

Answer (score 0):

Pictures of before and after of my monitor MSI Optix G27C2
( https://m.imgur.com/a/BXhSP7S ).
Rosenthal, Thank you so much this fixed my monitor. I thought it broke because I had lines running through it but no flickering, but just like ardavis I would change resolutions, and it would fix the issue until I restarted my computer. The steps are almost the same as of 2/13/20 on windows 10. All you have to do now is go to control panel> Hardware and Sound> Power Options, and there should be two options showing already  “Balanced (recommenced)” and “Power saver” look below them for a drop down to the right of “Show additional plans” click that, and all you have to do is click the “High performance” option and your done. All the settings that rosenthal recommenced to change was done automatically (in exception for aero basic theme that’s for windows 7 I believe). Keep in mind it will only turn off monitor after 15 minutes of inactivity by default if you want to change that or also want to turn on the option to put the computer to sleep after a certain inactivity timer too click the “Change plan settings” button to the right of the “High performance option”